# Git Hub Desktop on Mac, error: cannot run gpg: No such file or directory

Tags: macos, github, git-commit, github-for-mac

Trying to commit my changes by using GitHub Desktop and getting this:

[image]

> error: cannot run gpg: No such file or directory
>
> error: could not run gpg.
>
> fatal: failed to write commit object
> (128)

Firstly that not worked for terminal too and i create gpg-key and plugged in to my GitHub Account
Now it's  working well in Terminal but Desktop version still not working.

> In Oficial doccumentation for GitHub Desktop i found some notation:
>
> Note: GitHub Desktop does not support GPG signing.

Comment: What does `git status` show you when you see this error coming from GitHub Desktop?

Comment: Showing all changes, i used Win os before just trying to set mac and get this trouble...

Comment: Did you configure GitHub Desktop on your Mac?

Comment: Yes, Logged and Clone my Repo

Comment: I have the same issue. If work with git from console all ok. But if use GitHub app I have same error. Do you resolve issue?

Comment: No, i still waiting may be somebody has it...

Answer (score 238):

Solved it.

So as GitHub Desktop was complaining about not being able to find gpg (I had installed it via homebrew), I figured there should be a way to tell git the exact path of gpg, turns out there is:

> gpg.program
> Use this custom program instead of "gpg" found on $PATH when making or verifying a PGP signature. The program must support the same command-line interface as GPG, namely, to verify a detached signature, "gpg --verify $file - <$signature" is run, and the program is expected to signal a good signature by exiting with code 0, and to generate an ASCII-armored detached signature, the standard input of "gpg -bsau $key" is fed with the contents to be signed, and the program is expected to send the result to its standard output.
> https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config

So running the following solved the problem:

```sh
git config --global gpg.program "$(which gpg)"
```

GitHub got back to me and said that some users also need to use:

```sh
echo "no-tty" >> ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf
```

Comment: I've tried running both of these lines but still getting this error. Anyone else having problems?

Comment: Hi @captDaylight. I got the same issue. Do u have solution in this case?

Comment: FWIW, I was having this problem on vscode (Visual Studio Code), and the same solution fixed it. 

Comment: After installing big sur, git commit did not work from within vs code and complained about gpg: no such file or directory. This solved it for me.

Comment: `git config --global gpg.program $(which gpg)` alone fixed my issue

Answer (score 16):

It has something to do with **commit signing** (https://help.github.com/en/articles/signing-commits).

In case you use Github Desktop (which doesn't support *commit signing* as highlighted right at the beginning of the article linked above) or if you don't need *commit signing* (or don't even know what it is), one thing you can do is to disable **gpg commit signing** by running a command like `git config --global commit.gpgsign false` or edit your `.git/config` file manually:

```
[commit]
  # https://help.github.com/articles/signing-commits-using-gpg/
  gpgsign = false
```

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 13):

For Mac and gpg2 installed

```
git config --global gpg.program "$(which gpg2)"
```

This works for me.

And after above command, your .gitconfig should look like below

```
[user]
    email = yogesh.jadhav@xxx.com.au
    name = jadhavy
    signingkey = xxx
[credential]
    helper = osxkeychain
[gpg]
    program = /usr/local/MacGPG2/bin/gpg2
[commit]
    gpgsign = true
[core]
    autocrlf = input
```

Answer (score 4):

**SOLUTION FOR VSCODE USERS:**

Under settings search for GPG and uncheck it:

*[image: VS CODE IMAGE]*

*Now, why would you uncheck it?*

*You only need this extension if using the Gnu Privacy Guard. If you* *don't know what it is, then you definitely do not need to worry about it.*

*However, just in case you want to know what is going on check out:*
*https://www.gnupg.org/*