# How to fix 'cannot run --version: No such file or directory' error during Git commit GPG signing

Tags: git, github, atom-editor, gnupg, gpg-signature

### Initial Steps and Problem

---

I installed [**Git**](https://git-scm.com/downloads) on my Mac and then tried to set up **GPG** signature verification by following the steps outlined in [**Github**](https://help.github.com/en/articles/managing-commit-signature-verification).

The first time I did a test `git commit` through the Mac OS **Terminal** I was requested my passphrase and the commit was properly signed and pushed through. No problems.

Then I tested the signature verification through the [**Atom**](https://atom.io) editor. This time, however, the `git commit` signing failed.

### Initial attempts at find a Solution and additional Problem

---

I tried looking for solutions on **Stack Overflow** and **GitHub** but was unable to find any that worked although I did try some of the suggestions proposed.

Unfortunately, now when trying to `git commit` via the Terminal, I get the following error message:

> error: cannot run --version: No such file or directory
>   error: gpg failed to sign the data
>   fatal: failed to write commit object

I have spent a few days trying to find a solution online but have not been successful.

I do not understand the first line of the error message ( ***cannot run --version: no such file or directory*** ) and have not been able to find a similar issue online.

### Further attempts and trials at finding a Solution

---

Over the last couple of days I have tried a lot of things based on suggestions from the following sites:

- [gpg failed to sign the data fatal: failed to write commit object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494631/gpg-failed-to-sign-the-data-fatal-failed-to-write-commit-object-git-2-10-0)
- [Git Hub Desktop on Mac, error: cannot run gpg: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36941533/git-hub-desktop-on-mac-error-cannot-run-gpg-no-such-file-or-directory)
- [Automatic Git commit signing with GPG on OSX](https://gist.github.com/bmhatfield/cc21ec0a3a2df963bffa3c1f884b676b)
- [How to set up git to use the GPG Suite](https://gist.github.com/danieleggert/b029d44d4a54b328c0bac65d46ba4c65)

I have also done the following:

- Tested GPG signing through [**GitKraken**](https://www.gitkraken.com) which works without any issues.
- Tested with **GitHub Desktop** and got the following error:

  > Error: Commit failed - exit code 128 received, with output:
  >   'error: gpg failed to sign the data fatal: failed to write commit object'
- Tested with **Atom** editor and got the following error:

  > Unable to commit. Error: gpg failed to sign the data
  >   fatal: failed to write commit object
- Uninstalled **GnuPG** and reinstalled through [**Homebrew**](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/gnupg#default).
- In the end I even tried installing GPGTools' [**GPGSuite**](https://gpgtools.org).

Unfortunately the problem persists and I no longer know what to try.

The output that I got for `git config -l | grep -E 'gpg|sign` is:

> user.signingkey=00C23E4C0619F0BD
>   commit.gpgsign=true
>   gpg.program=/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin/gpg2

I could do the following:
`git config --global commit.gpgsign false`

But this would not resolve the issue and I would still not be able to sign my `git commit`.

What confuses and frustrates me is that it worked during my first `git commit` after setting everything up following the steps outlined in **Github's** official guidelines. I am not sure what I did since then so that it no longer works. I have tried to back track and erase any changes but so far I have still not been able to resolve this issue.

*Any help and guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!*

### Update 1

---

Out of curiosity I tried doing a `git commit` through **Terminal** with a different local repo. The commit went through without a glitch and when I checked on **Github** it was signed and *verified*. I did further tests to commit and sign via **GitHub Desktop** and **Atom**, everything works fine without any issues. This is good news and gives me hope. However, I still have no idea why `git commit` works on one repo and not on the other repo I was testing with. The original repo I was testing with still cannot `git commit` and gives the same error message that I detailed above... I wonder what is wrong?

### Additional Information

---

*I am running the following:*

- **macOS 10.14.4**
- **git 2.21.0**
- **gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.15**

Comment: Could include the output of `git config -l | grep -E 'gpg|sign'`, please?

Comment: @bk2204 please find the output below:  
user.signingkey=00C23E4C0619F0BD  
commit.gpgsign=true  
gpg.program=/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin/gpg2

Comment: ***Update***: @bk2204 out of curiosity I tried doing a `git commit` with another repo. The commit went through and when I checked on Github it was signed and verified. This is good news and gives me hope. However, I still have no idea why `git commit` works on one repo and not on the original repo I was testing with. Also the original repo still cannot `git commit` and gives the same error message explained above... I wonder what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update 2 and Solution

After testing, since the issue seems to be only on *one* of my local git repos and not on any other local git repos, I concluded that overall, **Git**, **GitHub Desktop**, **Atom**, and **GPG Signing** are all working fine and the issue is specific to that one local git repo.

Although I have tried my best and still not found out exactly what is wrong with the buggy git repo and because I don't seem to be getting any additional leads/solutions from **Stack Overflow** I decided to do the following:

- **Delete** *my local git repo* that had the issue.
- **Reclone** from the *remote repo*.
- After a successful `git clone` *redo tests* with `git commit` and ***GPG signing*** via the **Terminal**, **GitHub Desktop**, and **Atom**.
- All are now working fine.

I guess I might never know what really happened but I am glad to confirm that at least everything is working again normally. *Thank you @bk2204*