# How do I send files up to a new repo in Github using terminal?

Tags: github, terminal, uploading

When I try to send the project up to the new Github repo I created using:
git add .

Then:
git commit -m "first commit" I get:

fatal: cannot run gpg: No such file or directory
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object

I don't want to use drag and drop. I've already uploaded a zip file of the project manually using the drag and drop feature.

So in the terminal I type:
git init

This does initialise the local directory:
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /Users/iancraig/TRAINING/REACT/JOHN_SMILGA_REACT_COURSE_V3/react-course-v3-main/02-backroads-project/my-app/.git/

I then type:
git add .

Then:
git commit -m "first commit"

Which results in:

fatal: cannot run gpg: No such file or directory
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object

This is my first attempt at creating and connecting to a new repository in Github.
This is such a basic thing to attempt to do with Github so what's going on here?
I've downloaded and added a new SSH key successfully to my account.

Comment: Hi there, just a thought by looking at other similar posts on here I see this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37261769/21960203
Can you give the steps there a try?